# Python, Pycharm Flask import from package naming issues

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I have a directory structure for my Flask-Dash app:

[image]

I am following this tutorial:  https://dash.plotly.com/integrating-dash

to combine one or more Dash apps with a Flask app.

But in `wsgi.py`, it could not find a reference for `dash_app2.py` until I renamed it using Roman numerals `dash_appII.py`.

Is there a naming convention in Python where two files in the same package or directory cannot have similar names like `dash_app1.py` and `dash_app2.py`?

It could not even find a reference to `dash_app2.py` in the `__init__.py` file in that directory which now looks like:

```
from .dash_app1 import dash_app1
from .dash_appII import dash_app2
```

I don't really want to use Roman numerals.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you importing dash_app1 somewhere else in your app? I've found that the explicit relative import can sometimes cause namespace collisions if you use it after importing the packages somewhere else with a non-explicit import. Worth a shot to take a look or simply remove the . explicit and give it a go. All else hold equal, you shouldn't have issues importing the numeric versions of your files.

Comment: I just looked through my files  and it does not seem to be the case but it's a good point.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3?rq=1